# How to reorder records from sorted set on a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just curious to know if there is a way to achieve this:

I have a need to display some records based on user's paid for their items to appear on top of  a category that they wish.

I have found how to display them on top, but actually the most recent record is always appearing on top, which is actually not good.

Here is the result:

```
itemid, promoid, datepaid  
49, 8, 14/08/2013
32, 2, 12/08/2013
34, 0, null
35, 0, null
```

where: promid = 0 mean unpaid.
and upaid should come at the bottom.

What I need is to just reorder the promoid in ascending order so the ones who have paid first will appear on top.

All ads have an expiration, so the ones who are appearing on top will eventually expire and become non-ad items.

#### EDIT

Readers are unable to understand what I want. They simply downgrading the question without understanding the need.

I have clearly mentioned what I want. I dont need a simple query that just reorders on the basis of "promoid rather I want the ones who paid first should come on top.

NOTE: Before taking any action on my question, please **READ IT AGAIN**, and ask your questions in comments. I really dont like my question to be voted down without understanding the question.

Comment: What does your query look like now?

Comment: You're asking how to access database objects without any information related to the data objects/schema. Please provide table names, columns, etc.

Comment: @Zee, omg, dont you see the table and the data in it i have already mentioned? You totaly misunderstood the question.

Comment: @dean, well the base query is simple, it just pulls those columns from the two separate tables. UserItems and Promos. You can assume basic structure and form the query.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is to just reorder the promoid in ascending order

```
select itemid, promoid
from <table>
order by promoid asc
```